# cqlsh not connecting when configuring a two node cluster on windows server

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to configure a two node cluster with cassandra in windows r2 2008 So i installed cassandra community version in one server (10.xxx.0.1,10.xxx.0.2) And then I stopped the service and then edited the configuraton.yaml file in the conf folder.

The changes are:

- cluster_name
- commented the num_tokens
- gave the tokens in initial_token,
- seeds as 10.xxx.0.1,10.xxx.0.2,
- listen_addresses are their respective ip addresses which are 10.xxx.0.1,10.xxx.0.2,
- rpc_addresses are same as listen_address,
  endpointsnitch as gossip

I also changed the cassandra `rackdc.propertie`s file to `dc=DC1 rack=RAC1`.
and changed the cassandra-env file - uncommented: `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.xxx.0.1`

I then saved and started back the service and ran nodetool status and got

## Datacenter: DC1

```
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Owns (effective)  Host ID
    Token                                    Rack
UN  10.104.0.15  46.65 KB   100.0%            bc41a884-baaf-4a52-85f3-f3270c2ec9
57  -9223372036854775808                     RAC1
```

and opened the cqlsh, but it is not connecting. Below is the error:

```
ERROR [Initialization] 2015-10-12 17:10:21,353 Error connecting via JMX: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 17:10:24,612 Reconnecting to a backup OpsCenter instance
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 17:10:24,615 SSL communication is disabled
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 17:10:24,615 Creating stomp connection to 127.0.0.1:61620
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 17:10:24,628 Starting Jetty server: {:join? false, :ssl? false, :host nil, :port 61621}
   INFO [Initialization] 2015-10-12 17:10:24,632 Sleeping for 2s before trying to determine IP over JMX again
   INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-10-12 17:10:24,640 Reconnecting in 0s.

  INFO [main] 2015-10-12 18:25:56,347 Waiting for the config from OpsCenter
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 18:25:56,349 Attempting to determine Cassandra's broadcast address through JMX
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 18:25:56,350 Starting Stomp
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 18:25:56,350 Starting up agent communcation with OpsCenter.
   INFO [Initialization] 2015-10-12 18:25:56,356 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  ERROR [Initialization] 2015-10-12 18:25:57,652 Error connecting via JMX: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 18:26:00,768 Reconnecting to a backup OpsCenter instance
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 18:26:00,770 SSL communication is disabled
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 18:26:00,770 Creating stomp connection to 127.0.0.1:61620
   INFO [main] 2015-10-12 18:26:00,779 Starting Jetty server: {:join? false, :ssl? false, :host nil, :port 61621}
   INFO [Initialization] 2015-10-12 18:26:00,782 Sleeping for 2s before trying to determine IP over JMX again
   INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-10-12 18:26:00,945 Reconnecting in 0s.
   INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-10-12 18:26:01,136 Connected to 127.0.0.1:61620
```

Comment: have you tried `cqlsh 10.xxx.0.1` ?

Comment: Thank you I have tried it in the command prompt and it got connected to the cqlsh